# understanding threads why count not increase

Tags: c#, multithreading, console, thread-safety

I don't unrdersntat why with this code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("START PROGRAMN-----------------------------------");
        test();
        Console.WriteLine("END PROGRAMN-----------------------------------");
        Console.Read();
    }
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static int i;
    private static void test()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

            // define the event handlers
            bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("START Thread-------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Print:" + i);
            };
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("END Thread-------------");
                if (args.Error != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(args.Error.ToString());
                }
            };

            bw.RunWorkerAsync(); // starts the
        }
    }
```

It will show this in console:

```
START PROGRAMN-----------------------------------
END PROGRAMN-----------------------------------
START Thread-------------
Print:0
END Thread-------------
START Thread-------------
Print:0
END Thread-------------
```

Why second print doesn't show print 1?

I think the first iteration is correct because I see print: 0 but in second why I don't see print: 1?

EDIT FOR ANSER

Without [ThreadStatic]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("START PROGRAMN-----------------------------------");
        test();
        Console.WriteLine("END PROGRAMN-----------------------------------");
        Console.Read();
    }
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static int i;
    private static void test()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

            // define the event handlers
            bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("START Thread-------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Print:" + i);
            };
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("END Thread-------------");
                if (args.Error != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(args.Error.ToString());
                }
            };

            bw.RunWorkerAsync(); // starts the
        }
    }
```

It will show this in console:

```
START PROGRAMN-----------------------------------
END PROGRAMN-----------------------------------
START Thread-------------
Print:2
END Thread-------------
START Thread-------------
Print:2
END Thread-------------
```

Why first pirnt  doesn't show print 0 and second print 1?

why show 2?

Comment: Why did you tag this as ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about that `ThreadStatic` you are not using this properly. It's not what you need in you case. The problem you are trying to bypass is because otherwise your result gets the latest value because the DoEvent is not started on the first thread that it already changed. You end up with a race condition. You do need to use arguments to have clear local instance of the variable. the easiest way is to change your code like so

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
     var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

     // define the event handlers
     bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
     {
          // get the argument
          var value = args.Argument.ToString();
          Console.WriteLine("START Thread-------------");
          Console.WriteLine("Print:" + value);
     };
     bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
     {
         Console.WriteLine("END Thread-------------");
         if (args.Error != null)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(args.Error.ToString());
         }
     };

     bw.RunWorkerAsync(i); // starts the thread with arguments
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not really understand the `ThreadStatic` attribute here. It means that, by definition, `Indicates that the value of a static field is unique for every thread.` That means the value is unique for the Main Thread (where you are creating the BackgroundWorkers) and the BackgroundWorkers, that will always have the default value 0 for `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'Console.WriteLine("Print:" + i);' inside the lambda.
The "Print:" + i is not evaluated and concatenated while inside the for loop. It will be present in your anonymous method and only will be concatenated when that method runs.

Because of your [ThreadStatic] attribute, int i is not shared between threads. "Each executing thread has a separate instance of the field, and independently sets and gets values for that field. If the field is accessed on a different thread, it will contain a different value."

int i will be instantiated and you get the int default value.